# Set type of state of React Component with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am tryig to use `TypeScript` in my `React` project

```
export enum IngridientType {
  BreadBottom = "BreadBottom",
  BreadTop = "BreadTop",
  Meat = "Meat",
  Cheese = "Cheese",
  Bacon = "Bacon",
  Salad = "Salad",
  Seeds1 = "Seeds1",
  Seeds2 = "Seeds2",
}

export type IngredientsListType<R> = { [key in keyof typeof IngridientType]?: R };

type IBurgerBuilderState<T> = { ingredients: IngredientsListType<T> };

class BurgerBuilder extends Component<{}, IBurgerBuilderState<number>> {
  state = {
    ingredients: {
       [IngridientType.Bacon]: 2,
       [IngridientType.Cheese]: 2,
    },
  };

...
}
```

but I am getting an error

> Property 'state' in type 'BurgerBuilder' is not assignable to the same
>   property in base type 'Component<{}, IBurgerBuilderState,
>   any>'.   Type '{ ingredients: { [IngridientType.Salad]: number;
>   [IngridientType.Cheese]: number; }; }' is not assignable to type
>   'Readonly>'.

I don't understand exactly what is the problem here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was tweaking in the TypeScript playground with your code and came up with following approach - used your `enum` together with a simple `generic type`:

```
export enum IngridientType {
  BreadBottom = "BreadBottom",
  BreadTop = "BreadTop",
}

type IngridientsType<T extends string, U> = {
    [K in T]: U;
};

interface IState {
  ingredients: IngridientsType<IngridientType, number>;
}

const state: IState = {
  ingredients: {
    [IngridientType.BreadTop]: 0,
    [IngridientType.BreadBottom]: 2,
    someOtherIngredient: 'wrongType', // ts will throw errors on it
  }
}
```

**Edit**: if you'd ask me what is causing the error in your example, I'm not 100% sure. However the example above might be a little bit more *friendly*?

Comment: the same as before

Comment: @goskan93 Consider providing me your typescript version and the whole component mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
export enum IngridientType {
  BreadBottom = 'BreadBottom',
  BreadTop = 'BreadTop',
  Meat = 'Meat',
  Cheese = 'Cheese',
  Bacon = 'Bacon',
  Salad = 'Salad',
  Seeds1 = 'Seeds1',
  Seeds2 = 'Seeds2',
}

export type IngredientsListType<R> = Record<IngridientType, R>

type IBurgerBuilderState<T> = { ingredients: Partial<IngredientsListType<T>> }

export class BurgerBuilder extends Component<{}, IBurgerBuilderState<number>> {
  state = {
    ingredients: {
      [IngridientType.Bacon]: 2,
      [IngridientType.Cheese]: 2,
    },
  }
}
```

Since you are only initialising your state with a partial set you will need use `Partial`.
Also your `IngredientsListType` can be simplified with `Record`.

Side note, `Ingridient`  should be spelt `Ingredient`

https://codepen.io/drGreen/details/wvKeNyB

Comment: I bet `Partial` is redundant here since I think he wants ts to throw errors if not each entry from enum provided in state.

Comment: perhaps - it wasn't clear from his example, but this compiles in a React app now